# Using echo to print multiple forms in html with PHP

Tags: php, html

So I have this code that is supposed to print a bunch of boxed in results, that should function as forms to get any user's data, however when I store a huge html string into a variable to then print onto my html, it only appends the form tags once on one of the boxes. Why is this happening? It does not seem logical to me. This is what I have done with my code:

```
<?php 
    if($searchData == "" || $resultArray == null){
        echo "<h2>No results found<h2>";
    } else {
        foreach($resultArray as $iterator){
            $finalResult = $finalResult.'<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> 
                                            <div class="properties">
                                                <form action="user-detail.php" method="POST">
                                                    <h4>'.$iterator['USERNAME'].' </h4>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PERSON_NAME'].'</h5>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['FIRST_LAST_NAME'].'</h5>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['SECOND_LAST_NAME'].'</h5>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="username" value="'.$iterator['USERNAME'].'"/>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="p_id" value="'.$iterator['PERSON_ID'].'"/>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none"  readonly name="name" value="'.$iterator['PERSON_NAME'].'"/>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none"  readonly name="last_name" value="'.$iterator['FIRST_LAST_NAME'].'"/>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none"readonly name="second_last_name" value="'.$iterator['SECOND_LAST_NAME'].'"/>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="b_value" value="'.$iterator['BLACKLIST'].'"/>
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Details"
                                                <form/>
                                            </div>
                                           </div>';
        }
        echo $finalResult;
    }
?>
```

Normally, I wouldn't ask for help with this, but I have no clue why an error like this could happen. It makes no sense to me as to why this would happen. I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify as to why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ending form tag is improperly formatted.

You have: `<form/>`

It should be: `</form>`

I hope that helps!

Comment: Nope, its not that. I wish it had been though.

Comment: Your submit button is also missing the closing bracket. <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Details"/>

Comment: Yeah that did it. thanks, I can't believe I missed something like this. I've been working on this stupid project for too long.